# Matlab mex "Missing dependent shared libraries"

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2017, mex

I have a couple mex files I'm creating in Matlab 2017a. When I compile them with Visual Studio C++ 2017, they run fine on my computer. However, when I attempt to use them on another computer, I get an error that says

```
Error using mfss_mex.filter_uni
Invalid MEX-file  
'path_to_mex_file\mexfile.mexw64':
Missing dependent shared libraries:
'MSVCP140.dll' required by
'path_to_mex_file\mexfile.mexw64'
'VCRUNTIME140.dll' required by
'path_to_mex_file\mexfile.mexw64'
```

I think I could resolve this by installing the Visual Studio runtime on every computer this will get run on but I'd like to avoid that. Is there a way to compile these mex files and avoid these dependencies with the Visual Studio C++ compiler?

Comment: I've been able to compile these files before using another version of Matlab and Visual Studio for what it's worth without creating these dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mathworks [solution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/before-you-run-a-mex-file.html) to this is to install the C++ compiler runtime on any computer that has this issue.

I found that I simply needed to copy the offending `.dll` files (`MSVCP140.dll` and `VCRUNTIME140.dll`) into the same folder with my `.mexw64` files and everything ran without a problem.

Comment: Can't we place .dll and .mex64 files at different directories and add the paths to those directories using addpath command ?

Comment: I just ran into a situation that confirmed to me that yes, the .dll files need to be in the same directory as the .mexw files.

Comment: I also faced the same situation. If a matlab program refers to functions from a mexw file which in turn is defined in .dll then all of them (matlab program, mexw and .dll) have to be in the same directory. Putting them in different directories and adding paths via `addpath` command does NOT work !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by `re-mex` the original .c file in MATLAB;
If you have the original .c file, the simple  way is:

```
mex -setup
mex NAME.c
```

(Here NAME represents the name of your invalid .mexw64 file)
In this case, for example:

```
mex mexfile.c
```