# How to use dll generated by visual studio in another machine without visual studio installed?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2012, mex

I have generated dynamic library in visual studio 2012. I want to use that library in another machine, but I don't want to install visual studio in remote machine. 
I have mex library and dll and I want to run a script which uses both libraries. When I run the script I got the following error.
"Missing shared libraries: MSVCR110D.dll, MSVCP110D.dll"
Where do I need to place those dll's inorder to run my script file in matlab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab mex "Missing dependent shared libraries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315942/matlab-mex-missing-dependent-shared-libraries)

Answer (score 4):

`MSVCR110D.dll` and `MSVCP110D.dll` are debug libraries. If your library requires them, then that means that your library was built in Debug mode, with all of the debug symbols in it.

Never ship an application/library with debug symbols in them! Instead, if you build your application in Release mode, then it will depend on the non-debug versions instead. If those do not come with Windows normally, you'll need to install the required redist pack.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install microsoft redistributable for vs2012, also you should compile your library in release mode.

Comment: Unless you want to get a core dump, in which case debug mode is perfectly reasonable - it's all about the shipping that you don't want to do.